# boost, matrix_proxy, const matrix

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ublas

Giving this:

```
void foo(const matrix<double>& lol)
{
    matrix_row<matrix<double> > lolwut(lol, 5);
}
```

error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_row<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> >::matrix_row(const boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>&, size_t&)’
```

How to `unconst` the reference given in the function's parameter or which workaround to use? I'm not sure if simple assignment

```
matrix<double> tmp = lol;
```

will not have any overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do this using `BOOST_AUTO`:

```
void foo(const matrix<double>& lol)
{
    matrix_row< const matrix<double> > lolwut(lol, 5);
}
```

The spaces are needed if you are compiling to C++ < 11 otherwise some buggy compilers will interpret it as a right bit-shift (`>>`) operator

Answer (score 1):

Try using `BOOST_AUTO`.

**Code:**

```
BOOST_AUTO(r, row(lol, 5));
```

Comment: It is obvious, thanks! I figured it out right after I questioned. The solution is  matrix_row<matrix<double> > lolwut((matrix<double>) lol, 5);